# The comment box placed in the wrong place wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-shortcode

I want to add a new shortcode with this function in wordpress with flatsome theme and show comment box in a desired location in accardion, but after add this shortcode to page, comment box show in top of the page instead in accardion:

```
add_shortcode('my_comment_box', 'my_comment_box');
function my_comment_box() {
     $commentbox=comment_form();
     echo $commentbox;
}
```

I tested this code with return command instead of  echo, But the problem was not solved
what is wrong?

Comment: Because you need to `return $commentbox;` and not echo it probably

Comment: I mentioned in the text above I also used the return command and error not fixed

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem with ob_start() and return ob_get_clean():

```
add_shortcode('my_comment_box', 'my_comment_box');
function my_comment_box() {
     ob_start();
     $commentbox=comment_form();
     echo $commentbox;
     return ob_get_clean();
}
```